# How to rotate first and last x-axis label in Highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, rotation, axis

I would like to rotate only firt and last label in x-axis.
I have following formatter function:

```
formatter() {
    if (this.isFirst || this.isLast) {
        // First or last label here
        var rotatedValue = this.value.doRotation();   // TODO here
        return rotatedValue;
    } else {
        return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
    }
},
```

I did a research but nothing found (how call some rotation function).
I use a basic line chart.

Comment: what kind of graph/chart are you using? line? bar?

Comment: I use a line chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `xAxis.labels.useHTML` option to `true` and style these labels via **CSS3**:

```
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      useHTML: true
    }
  },

  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var div = this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.div;

        div.firstChild.style.transform = "rotate(30deg)";
        div.lastChild.style.transform = "rotate(30deg)";
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/fepj1f5g/

**API reference:** http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML

Comment: Weird, it is not working for me. Both labels disappeared.

Comment: Please provide a minified demo of your code (live working example ideally).